# ORDER BY, SELECT statement, Duplicate Code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below stored procedure and depending on the @AreaNumber parameter, it will run the exact same query but with a different order by clause.

Is there a way I can combine the two queries, rather than having the IF statement?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAlerts]
    @AreaNumber tinyint = NULL

IF @AreaNumber is NULL
    SELECT *
    FROM alerts
    ORDER BY DateModified DESC, DateCreated DESC
ELSE
    SELECT * 
    FROM alerts
    ORDER BY IsPermanent ASC, DateModified DESC, DateCreated DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY` can be an arbitrary expression, so you could move your `IF` inside the query itself (but as a `CASE` expression instead):

```
select * from alerts
    ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @AreaNumber IS NULL THEN '-' ELSE IsPermanent END) ASC,
             DateModified DESC,
             DateCreated DESC
```

I don't have a SQL Server instance handy to test for quirks, but the '-' is essentially meant to be a dummy stand in. It will have the same value for all rows, so therefore won't affect sorting.

Comment: Thanks for that, but isn't your code going to sort by IsPermanent regardless of whether AreaNumber is NULL or not?  It shouldn't sort by IsPermanent if the value of @AreaNumber is NULL.

Comment: You may also need to change '-' to match the type of `IsPermanent`; it wasn't clear from the example what the specific data type of that column was.

Comment: [Parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) may impact the performance. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do it using `CASE` either in `ORDER BY` clause or using ROW_NUMBER().

```
SELECT *
FROM alerts
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @AreaNumber IS NOT NULL THEN IsPermanent ELSE '' END
,   DateModified DESC
,   DateCreated DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT *
,   CASE WHEN @AreaNumber IS NOT NULL 
    THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IsPermanent ASC, DateModified DESC, DateCreated DESC)
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateModified DESC, DateCreated DESC)
    END RN  
FROM alerts
```

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` will add an extra column (row number), so maybe making it a sub-query will be a better idea. However, I just want to give you more options as it might help out.